# array manipulation and rearranging

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my deal.
I have this array:

```
Array // called $data in my code
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => var_id
            [value] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => var_id
            [value] => 5
        )

)
```

which I need it to be like:

```
Array // called $temp in my code
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => quantity
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => var_id
                    [value] => 4
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => quantity
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => var_id
                    [value] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

and I did it using this code I made:

```
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $temp = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $datum)
    {
        if($key%2 == 0)
        {
            $temp[$key] = array();
            array_push($temp[$key], $datum, $data[$key+1]);
        }
    }
```

But I think that my code is some kinda stupid, specially if I have a huge data.
eventually what I want to do is just have each two indexes combined in one array, and I know that there should be something better than my code to do it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discover [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$temp = array_chunk($data, 2);
```

Comment: Oh nice, did not know about that one

Comment: +1, that's a great answer, love it.
didn't know such a function exists :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$cnt = count($data);
$temp = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i = $i + 2)
{
    $temp[] = array($data[$i], $data[$i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(1),
    array(2),
    array(3),
    array(4),
);

print_r(
    array_chunk($array, 2, false)
);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
            )
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
            )
        )
    )
*/
```